# Laplace Transform involving 1/x

Tags: numerical-methods, laplace-transform

I'm encountering a problem in which the following identity is used

$\frac{1}{x} = \int_0^\infty \exp(-xt) \mathrm{d}t$, where $x$ is real and positive,

which is derived "with a Laplace transform". However, I cannot see how this works out. The Laplace transform of 1/x is

$F(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t} \exp(-st) \mathrm{d}t$,

which is a divergent integral. Then, how do you obtain the equation above?

Comment: It is the Laplace transform of $1$, not $1/x$

Comment: The inverse of the Laplace transform is not the Laplace transform itself

Comment: Nothing is ever really "derived with a Laplace transform", except using identities that relate one LT to another. Rather, certain integrals that happen to be LTs can be computed, by a wide variety of techniques. Out of curiosity, in which problem did you see this rewrite of $1/x$ being used?

Comment: I have encountered it in the context of quantum-chemistry (QC) in a paper from 1991 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(91)80078-C). The key equation is (3) and the text before that equation. This method has stuck within the QC community as a 'Laplace transform technique' to this day, which I don't really understand considering PierreCarre's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the integral directly... No need to consider the Laplace transform.

$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx} dt = \left[-\frac{1}{x} e^{-tx}\right]_{t=0}^{\infty} = \frac 1x, \quad x>0
$$